# Python : Increasing recursion function call while profiling memory

Tags: python, recursion, google-colaboratory, memory-profiling

I'm  trying to study about recursive functions. I'm using Colaboratory to run my code.

Here's my question: why does the number of function calls increase while using a memory profiler? I used a global variable to count how many times the function was called.

This is my original code without the profiler:

```
# imports and other things...

accm = 0
def sum_num(n):
    global accm
    accm += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n + sum_num(n - 1)

call_list = []
for i in range(0, 6000, 100):
    accm = 0
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
    sum_num(i)
    call_list.append(accm)

# visualization things...
```

And set recursion limit to 10000.

The graph visualizing `accm` is linear from 1 to 6000:

[image]

And I expected this would not change when I use a profiler, but it did.

Here is the profiled version:

```
# imports and other things...
from memory_profiler import memory_usage

accm = 0
def sum_num(n):
    global accm
    accm += 1
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return n + sum_num(n - 1)


call_list = []
for i in range(0, 6000, 100):
    accm = 0
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
    _ = max(memory_usage((sum_num, (i,))))
    call_list.append(accm)

# visualization things...
```

And what I got is a nonlinear graph from 1 to about 16000; its maximum point is about 20000, and it increases linearly with noise until x = 25 and y = 16000, decreases, then increases linearly again with noise:

[image]

I want to know why this happens, and how to fix it.

Comment: I think this is going to depend almost entirely on how your memory profiler is implemented. What library is it from? Have you read its documentation? It seems likely that it's running the function you give it several times to get an average memory usage (and the number of times for each call changes at various breakpoints, perhaps related to runtime).

Comment: @Blckknght I used https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiler you're using will run the function you pass to `memory_usage` multiple times as it tries to identify a memory sampling interval that will let it get enough samples to have an accurate reading. If your code runs too quickly, it will need to shrink the sample size more, so the function will get called more often.

You can see how it works in the [source code of `memory_profiler`](https://github.com/pythonprofilers/memory_profiler/blob/ad64e49aed8db710b0b8ae8cd1694b5f95ab5540/memory_profiler.py#L323). Here's the important loop (with irrelevant stuff cut out):

```
while True:
    child_conn, parent_conn = Pipe() # this will store MemTimer's results
    p = MemTimer(os.getpid(), interval, child_conn, backend,
                 timestamps=timestamps,
                 max_usage=max_usage,
                 include_children=include_children)
    #...
    returned = f(*args, **kw)
    #...
    n_measurements = parent_conn.recv()
    #...
    if n_measurements > 4 or interval < 1e-6:
        break
    interval /= 10.
```

My interpretation of your output graph is that when your function is called with a small input, the `interval` needs to be shrunk three times before the profiler has sufficient resolution to measure the memory usage accurately, so the number of calls to the recursive function is four times the normal level. After iteration 22 or so, the interval only needs to be shrunk twice, so the graph values change to be three times the normal level. There's also some noise though where an unusually fast or slow run of the code results in an unusual number of interval changes needing to be done. This is why you see a few valleys where fewer resizings were needed, and one peak where an extra one happened.

You might be able to avoid the resizings if you pass an appropriate `interval` argument to `memory_usage`. The default is `0.1`, so you could probably avoid all the resizings by passing `0.0001` as the initial value (but consider experimenting, you might be able to do `0.0005` or more): `memory_usage((sum_num, (i,)), 1e-4)`

Comment: It worked, when I passed interval=1e-7. Thank you for answering.